# JavaScript replace using regex for all multiline space and other whitespace characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a textarea and I'm using jQuery to delete all tabs, newlines, multi spaces etc with a single space whenever the text area is blurred.

However, when I use the following:

```
str.replace(/\s/g, ' ')
```

...it deletes all tabs and newlines but not the multi spaces.

When I try:

```
str.replace(/[ \s], ' ')
```

...the same thing happens.

When I try:

```
str.replace(/[(?= +)\s], ' ')
```

...it won't escape my parentheses, etc.

Anyone know the correct syntax for what I'm trying to do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
str.replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KrqDH/

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping for a general solution I could use anywhere though. For example, what if instead of all whitespace I wanted only newlines, some random other character, and multispaces? Basically I was hoping for something that would allow me to use the [ ]s.

Comment: @saccharine, your requirements aren't clear to me. The solution can be generalised by adding the characters you want to a character class and adding the `+` operator. E.g. multiple r's and spaces would be `[r\s]+`. You can also replace the characters with their own matches: `str.replace(/([r\s])+/, '$1')`

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it. I was thinking about regex in the wrong way.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider looking at [Mozilla's Regular Expression Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions). This covers pretty much anything you would want to know about JavaScript regular expressions.

For the first part of your question, the regular express you want is `/\s+/`, where the `+` operator will match one or more of the previous statement in the expression (whitespace characters).

```
str.replace(/\s+/g, ' ')
```

On the second part:

```
str.replace(/[(?= +)\s], ' ')
```

This produces a syntax error. Do you mean `/[(?= +)\s]/`?

Comment: Hi, can you give a more general solution using [ ]? What if I wanted to also search for some random other character or set of characters?

Comment: It depends on the characters you want to match. Some characters are special (e.g. `?`, `[`, `]`, `(`, `)`,...) and need to be escaped with a backslash (`\?`). See [this list of special characters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Using_Special_Characters).